# MongoDB Nesting ElemMatch and All

Tags: mongodb

I want to find a list of Parents who have both a 3 year old child and a 4 year old child.

I have this query that seems to work:

```
db.SubArrays.find({
    Children: {$all: 
        [
               { "$elemMatch": { Age: 3}},
               { "$elemMatch": { Age: 4}}            
        ]
    }
})
```

I can't seem to get it converted over to Queries in c#

Given this data:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5514c620923a9b55e22f0adf"),
    "Name" : "Bob",
    "Children" : [ 
        {
            "Name" : "Kid1",
            "Age" : 5
        }, 
        {
            "Name" : "Kid2",
            "Age" : 4
        }, 
        {
            "Name" : "Kid3",
            "Age" : 4
        }
    ]
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5514c655923a9b55e22f0ae0"),
    "Name" : "Steve",
    "Children" : [ 
        {
            "Name" : "Kid4",
            "Age" : 3
        }, 
        {
            "Name" : "Kid5",
            "Age" : 4
        }, 
        {
            "Name" : "Kid6",
            "Age" : 4
        }
    ]
}
```

Should return

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5514c655923a9b55e22f0ae0"),
    "Name" : "Steve",
    "Children" : [ 
        {
            "Name" : "Kid4",
            "Age" : 3
        }, 
        {
            "Name" : "Kid5",
            "Age" : 4
        }, 
        {
            "Name" : "Kid6",
            "Age" : 4
        }
    ]
}
```

I've messed with this chunk of code, but I can't seem to figure out the second argument for Query.All()

```
    var ages = new List<int>();
    ages.Add(4);
    ages.Add(3);


    var threeQuery = Query<Child>.EQ(x => x.Age, 3);
    var fourQuery = Query<Child>.EQ(x => x.Age, 4);

    var child3Query = Query<Parent>.ElemMatch(x => x.Children, b => threeQuery);
    var child4Query = Query<Parent>.ElemMatch(x => x.Children, b => fourQuery);
    Query<Parent>.All(x => x.Children);
```

Comment: May be you should change your query as below

`db.collectionName.find({"$and":[{"Children.Age":3},{"Children.Age":4}]}).pretty()` Or `db.collectionName.find({"Children.Age":{"$all":[3,4]}})`

Comment: That would be fine, but I need to get that converted over to the c# driver syntax too.